# Fourier transform of $1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}$

Tags: integration, limits, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

So far I have tried the following:
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}(f)&=\mathscr{F}\{1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T}\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{|\tau|}{2T})e^{-i\omega\tau}d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(1+\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{-i\omega\tau}d\tau+\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{-i\omega\tau}d\tau\\
\end{align}$$
We use the method `change of variables` for the first integral $\tau=-\phi$ , $d\tau=-d\phi$ , $\tau=0\Rightarrow \phi=0$ , $\tau=-\infty\Rightarrow \phi=+\infty$ so the first integral will be:

$\int_{-\infty}^{0}(1+\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{-i\omega\tau}d\tau=\int_{+\infty}^{0}(1-\frac{\phi}{2T})e^{i\omega\phi}(-d\phi)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\phi}{2T})e^{i\omega\phi}d\phi=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{i\omega\tau}d\tau$

So we will have
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}(f)&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{i\omega\tau}d\tau+\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})e^{-i\omega\tau}d\tau\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})(e^{i\omega\tau}+e^{-i\omega\tau})d\tau  
\end{align}$$

Now from `integration by parts` method we have:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Derivation}& \text{Integration} \\
\hline
\oplus \quad 1-\frac{\tau}{2T} & e^{i\omega\tau}+e^{-i\omega\tau} \\
\ominus\quad -\frac{1}{2T} & \frac{1}{i\omega}(e^{i\omega\tau}-e^{-i\omega\tau})\\
\oplus \quad0 & \frac{-1}{\omega^2}(e^{i\omega\tau}+e^{-i\omega\tau})
\end{array}$$
$$\mathscr{F}(f)=[(1-\frac{\tau}{2T})\frac{1}{i\omega}(e^{i\omega\tau}-e^{-i\omega\tau})-\frac{1}{2T\omega^2}(e^{i\omega\tau}+e^{-i\omega\tau})]_0^{+\infty}$$
But I don't seem to get to the right answer, which is: $2T[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega T}]^2$

P.S. please don't recommend me to use propositions of fourier transform like linearity and etc. Also I don't want to use known fourier transdorms. I want to see what's wrong with my integration and my limit calculation in the infity an etc.

Comment: WolframAlpha does not agree with you: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierTransform[1-|x|%2Cx]`

Comment: The first simplification: Fourier transform is linear. The second simplification: Fourier transform of $1$ is $\delta_0$ (up to a multiplicative constant). Thus, you need to find only $\mathcal F[|\tau|](\omega)$. And, as memory serves me right, it was answered on this site.

Comment: Yes but i want to see if i have used the definition of fourier transform properly. I don't want to use propositions like linearity and i also don't want to use known fourier transforms. I want to see what's wrong with my integration and limits calculation in the infinity

Comment: I think you really want the FT of $$\left (1-\frac{|\tau|}{2 T}\right ) \theta(2 T-|\tau|) $$  where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \left (1-\frac{|\tau|}{2 T}\right ) \theta(2 T-|\tau|) e^{i \omega \tau} &= \int_{-2 T}^{2 T} d\tau \left (1-\frac{|\tau|}{2 T}\right )  e^{i \omega \tau}\\ &= \frac{2 \sin{2 \omega T}}{\omega}  - \frac{1}{T} \int_0^{2 T} d\tau \, \tau \, \cos{\omega \tau}\\ &= \frac{2 \sin{2 \omega T}}{\omega}  - \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \int_0^{2 T} d\tau \, \sin{\omega \tau} \\ &=\frac{2 \sin{2 \omega T}}{\omega}  - \frac{2}{T}\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \frac{\sin^2{\omega T}}{\omega}  \\ &= 2 T \frac{\sin^2{\omega T}}{(\omega T)^2}\end{align}$$

as you wanted to show.

Comment: why do you use $e^{i\omega\tau}$ instead of $e^{-i\omega\tau}$? Also could you please include the answer to my original question in your aswer? I want to see if the solution of the tutorial is wrong?

Comment: @sepideh: I use the + because that is how I learned forward Fourier transforms.  The answer in this case is identical.  What is the original question?  To anticipate what it may possibly be, sometimes people who are not being clear leave out the $\theta$ function and assume finite integration limits.  It should be clear, though, that the infinite integration limits leads to, uh, difficulties.